# Google Sheets IfElse function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to simple ledger function, where the user provides a QUANTITY and INDIVIDUAL PRICE as well as "buy" or "sell" in a separate columns. I have a field for the total change--if the user wrote "buy" in the specified column, the total change will be negative, if they wrote "sell" it will be positive. If neither of those words exists, it will show ERROR.

I wrote this function for the total change column but don't know how to include an "IFELSE" part to it: `=IF(B3 = "Buy", -(C3 * D3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheets built-in functions doesn't include a IFELSE function.

There are several ways to achieve a similar behavior like nesting IF functions, using other functions (LOOKUP, VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, MATCH and INDEX, ...) or build a custom function using Google Apps Script.

Example of nested IFs

```
=IF(B3 = "Buy", -(C3 * D3),IF(B3 = "Sell", (C3 * D3),"ERROR"))
```